# How do I beat level 7 of TOWLDR?

Tags: towldr

In [TOWLDR](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Hamumu/towldr), I can't figure out how to beat level 7. While it finishes on it's own eventually, and you can continue since the game operates on the honor system, I don't think I can get the best ending with that much time, and it's really boring. I noticed that clicking the letters makes them show up big(except "7", which "2"), but this doesn't seem to do anything. How do I complete this level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since it was entered as part of Ludum Dare 26, I was able to [download the source code](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-26/comment-page-1/?action=preview&uid=11). After looking through it for a while, I was able to find the relevant parts. Of particular interest was these:

```
public override function SpecialClick():void
{
    // LOADER2: click letters to embiggen them, GO is the answer
    // LOADINGLEVEL2
```

and

```
if (letter1.alpha > 0 && letter2.alpha > 0 && letter1.text == "G" && letter2.text == "O")
{
    letter1.alpha = 1;
    letter2.alpha = 1;
    loadBar.scale.x += FlxG.elapsed;
```

So, apparently, it has nothing to do with the "2". I guess that's just a mistake resulting from the levels' being named differently than the levels in the game. **The actual answer is to make it say "GO".**